# Proof verification - sums and products of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed and assume that $a_i, b_i, c_i\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ for all $i\in\{1, \dots, k\}$ verify the inequality
$$a_i\le b_i^{1/2} c_i^{1/2}\qquad\forall i\in\{1, \dots, k\}.$$

As an exercise, I have to derive an attainable upper bound for the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$ involving $\sum_{i=1}^k b_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k c_i$.

I argued in this way:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\le \sum_{i=1}^k (b_i^{1/2} c_i^{1/2}) \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_i^{1/2}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^k c_i^{1/2}\right)\le k \left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k c_i\right)^{1/2}.$$

Anyone could please tell me if I am right or not?

Comment: "*derive a suitable inequality*" $\;-\;$ Define "*suitable*".

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc what do you mean? Is that correct?

Comment: @Physicsuser After the edit, "*an upper bound*" is better than the former "*suitable*" but still not precise enough. If some expression $M$ is an upper bound, then so will be $2 M$. Maybe you mean an _attainable_ upper bound? FWIW the upper bound you propose is not attainable unless $k=1$.

Comment: @dxiv, could you please suggest which is an attainable upper bound which does hold also for the case $k>1$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you get the upper bound $(\sum b_i)^{1/2}(\sum c_i)^{1/2}$ which is better than yours as there is no factor $k.$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's right. It is like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the former $\leq$ and concavity of $\phi(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for the latter.